# ImgurSession file not found in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, imgur

I'm not being able to use ImgurSession in Swift because the file 'IMGResponseSerializer.h' can't find 'AFURLResponseSerialization.h'. Used cocoa pods to install it and AFNetworkings was also installed by ImgurSession. What's the best approach to fix this?

My cocoapods file:

```
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'ImgurSession', '~> 1.2
```

I'm not using Bridging-Header

Comment: What does your Podfile look like? Do you have a bridging header?

Comment: What do your target and project header search paths look like?

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is to use a bridging header in your project. Not every pod configuration works with `use_frameworks!`.

Change your Podfile to

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'ImgurSession', '~> 1.2
```

Add a bridging header. The easiest way is to create a dummy Objective-C file and allow Xcode to create a bridging header.

Instead of `#import "ImgurSession.h"` in the bridging header, add the specific imports that you need from the following:

```
#import "IMGSession.h"

#import "IMGAccountRequest.h"
#import "IMGAlbumRequest.h"
#import "IMGCommentRequest.h"
#import "IMGConversationRequest.h"
#import "IMGGalleryRequest.h"
#import "IMGImageRequest.h"
#import "IMGNotificationRequest.h"
#import "IMGMemeGen.h"

#import "IMGObject.h"
#import "IMGGalleryObject.h"

#import "IMGAccount.h"
#import "IMGAccountSettings.h"
#import "IMGAlbum.h"
#import "IMGBasicAlbum.h"
#import "IMGComment.h"
#import "IMGConversation.h"
#import "IMGNotification.h"
#import "IMGGalleryAlbum.h"
#import "IMGGalleryImage.h"
#import "IMGGalleryProfile.h"
#import "IMGImage.h"
#import "IMGMessage.h"
#import "IMGMeme.h"
#import "IMGVote.h"
```

Comment: The problem is the ImgurSession not finding AFNetworking

Comment: As far as I can tell, ImgurSession does not yet support being built as a framework.